# Expectation of the square of a geometric random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a geometric random variable with success parameter $p$. I am wondering how I could calculate $E[(X^2)]$, that is the expectation of the square of a geometric random variable. I know that for just $E(X)$ we can calculate it by differentiating a power series, but I'm unsure of how to carry this over to $E[(X^2)]$. I've tried to do this by using the fact $E[(X^2)] = E(X)+ [E(X(X-1)]$.

Comment: I think you mean the expectation _of the square of_ a geometric random variable. "Expectation squared ____" would seem to mean "square of expectation ____".

Comment: You have the good method. In the term $\mathbb{E} (X(X-1))$ you will recognize a second order derivative of $(1-p)^k$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, that makes more sense.

Comment: @nicomezi, make that second derivative of $(1 - p)^k z^k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the OP, we calculate $E(X(X-1))$.

There are two closely related versions of the geometric. In one of them, we count the number of **trials** until the first success. So the possible values are $1,2,3,\dots$. In the other version, one counts the number of **failures** until the first success. We use the first version. Minor modification will deal with the second.

Thus $\Pr(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$, and 
$$E(X(X-1))=\sum_{k=2}^\infty pk(k-1)(1-p)^{k-1}.$$
Consider the function 
$$f(t)=\frac{p}{1-t}=p(1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+t^5+\cdots).$$
Note that
$$f''(t)=p((2)(1)+(3)(2)t+(4)(3)t^2+(5)(4)t^3+\cdots),$$
and therefore
$$tf''(t)=p((2)(1)t+(3)(2)t^2+(4)(3)t^3+(5)(4)t^4+\cdots).$$ 
Finally, set $t=1-p$, and note that $f''(t)=\frac{2p}{(1-t)^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is kinda late but I think this solution can be easier to understand since you know how to get $E[X]$ using differentiation.

We should solve $E[X(X-1)]$ but we can use the same differentiation method for it:

$E[X(X-1)] $

$= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)p(1-p)^{k-1}$

$= p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)(1-p)^{k-1}$

$= p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)(1-p)^{k-2}(1-p)$

$= p(1-p)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)(1-p)^{k-2}$

$= p(1-p)(-\frac{d}{dp}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-1})$

$= p(1-p)(-\frac{d}{dp}(-\frac{d}{dp}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k}))$

$= p(1-p)(\frac{d}{dp}(\frac{d}{dp}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k}))$

$= p(1-p)(\frac{d}{dp}(\frac{d}{dp}(\frac{1}{p}-1)))$

$= p(1-p)(\frac{d}{dp}(-\frac{1}{p^2}))$

$= p(1-p)(\frac{2}{p^3})$

$= (\frac{2(1-p)}{p^2})$

$= (\frac{2q}{p^2})$

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the event that the first trial of the geometric distribution is a success:

$P(A) = p$

$P({A^c})=1-p$

Then

$E({X^2} |A)= 1 $ and

$E({X^2}|{A^c}) = E({(X+1)^2})$ since the first trial has already been counted as a failure.

then

$E({X^2}) = E({X^2}|A)P(A) + E({(X+1)^2}|{A^c})P({A^c})$

$ E({X^2})=1p + E({X^2} +2X +1)P({A^c})$

$E({X^2})=1p + (E({X^2}) + 2E(X) + 1)(1-p)$

You know $E(X)=1/p$ so you can just solve for $E({X^2})$

($(2-p)/{p^2}$)

Answer (score 0):

A geometric distribution has probability mass function (pmf):

$$P(X=n)=p(1-p)^n$$

Now:

$$E(X)=\sum^\infty_n nP(X=n)$$

$$E(X^2)=\sum^\infty_n n^2P(X=n)$$

So for the geometric distribution:

$$E(X^2)=\sum^\infty_n n^2p(1-p)^n$$

$$E(X^2)=p\sum^\infty_n n^2(1-p)^n$$

$$E(X^2)=p\left(\frac{p^2-3 p+2}{p^3}\right)$$

$$E(X^2)=\frac{p^2-3 p+2}{p^2}$$

Comment: 1. It's a PMF, not a PDF. 2. That doesn't say anything about how to compute those sums.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the variance of the geometric distribution, you can retrieve $E[X^2]$ from there:

$var(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2 => E[X^2]=var(X)+E[X]^2 = \frac{1-p}{p^2}+(\frac{1}{p})^2 = \frac{2-p}{p^2}$